# Scrolling in browser in an Ionic Project

Tags: css, macos, scroll, ionic-framework

I have a project since today. I have an ionic project who comes from a Windows and I can't scroll the view in my web browser.
But when I create a project in Mac OSX I can scroll like a charm with maintaining my left click mouse and scroll (like it would be tactile).

So can someone help me to make this new project scrollable in Mac OSX please ?

Many thanks.

Comment: It's usually best if you post a sample of the programming code you have written that is not working in your SO question to help us understand what you are talking about.

Comment: @Kmeixner Hi man. I'm not against it but it is my entirely project who don't scroll in my browser so I have something like 20 html files, 15 js files etc.. xD. Thing is, in windows the thing who cause the scroll is the "mouse wheel" who doesn't exist on mac and I don't know where it change

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have added to my ionic projects that do not need Cordova plugins the platform "Browser" to be able to deploy rapidly a nice webapp.

I faced the same issue and had to add this CSS property :

```
.isBrowserView {
    overflow-y: auto !important;
  }
```

On my app.run(), I have add the following code :

```
var deviceInformation = ionic.Platform.device();
if (deviceInformation.platform === "browser"){
    $rootScope.isBrowser = true;
}else{
    $rootScope.isBrowser = false;
}
```

Finally, I add this ng-class condition on my ion-contents

```
  <ion-content ng-class="{ isBrowserView : isBrowser== true } ">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, that was because my colleagues hadn't add "ion-content" in their html files. +1

Comment: Where `deviceInformation` comes from? pls add complete code.

Comment: Thanks! work for me too, but i used ionic default class PSB and set media-query for actual desktop.

    @media screen and (min-width:762px) {
       .platform-browser ion-content{
        overflow-y: auto !important;
      }
    }